# Want popup window on download link...to prompt for save,open,cancel

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

In my jsp page, i have provided one link to view/download scanned documents.

after clicking that link i can view document properly, But i want jsp to prompt for **Open, Save or cancel** option before opening that document.

Do i have to make some changes with response object or is it happening due to browser settings..??

Thanks.....!!!

I have written my controller class like this:

```
public void fileUploadOption(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
              // get your file as InputStream
              InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(\\..file..\\));


              IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

              response.flushBuffer();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

              throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`. This will force a *Save As* dialog.

Add this line *before* you're writing any byte to the response body:

```
String filename = file.getName();
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

---

By the way, "upload" is the wrong term in this context. I'd rename that method to `fileSendOption` or `sendFile` or something.

Comment: Why you mentioned one more back slash("\"") at the end of the statement...??

Comment: To escape the doublequote. The filename is surrounded by two doublequotes. Otherwise the header will be invalid when the filename contains spaces.

Comment: :thanks a lot... i was facing same problem since last two days....thank you so much